Euler power limit
Hi I Have this limit and I Have no idea how to apply the euler limit to this limit:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^x$$
I'm thinking I could write this as:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x-1+2}{x-1}\right)^x$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x-1}{x-1}+\frac{2}{x-1}\right)^x$$
Noe what do I do?I'm stuck here!The teacher didn't show us a method to solve this limit!

Good stuff so far. Next, make a substitution of $y = x - 1$.

even better, $y=(x-1)/2$
